# Why does introducing std::mutex to member class generate this compile error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stdmutex

In the code below, `class B` contains an array of member class `class A`.
`B::A` has one member `bool` and one member `std::thread`.
The code below compiles fine:

```
// main.cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class B {
public:
  B();

private:

  class A {
    public:
      A( const bool& b ) : b_( b ) {}

      bool b_;
      std::thread thread_;
  } a_[2];
};

B::B() : a_{ { false }, { false } } { }

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  B b;

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$
```

**Why does introducing a std::mutex to `B::A` introduce the following compile error?**

```
// main.cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class B {
public:
  B();

private:

  class A {
    public:
      A( const bool& b ) : b_( b ) {}

      bool b_;
      std::mutex mutex_;  // I break compilation!
      std::thread thread_;
  } a_[2];
};

B::B() : a_{ { false }, { false } } { }

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  B b;

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -g ./main.cpp
./main.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
./main.cpp:21:35: error: use of deleted function ‘B::A::A(B::A&&)’
 B::B() : a_{ { false }, { false } } { }
                                   ^
./main.cpp:11:9: note: ‘B::A::A(B::A&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   class A {
         ^
./main.cpp:11:9: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/mutex:44:0,
                 from ./main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/std_mutex.h:97:5: note: declared here
     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
     ^~~~~
```

If I correctly understand the compile error, it's complaining that an instance of `B::A` cannot be created without explicit construction of `B::A::mutex_`. But if this is true, I don't understand why this should be necessary: `std::mutex` has a default constructor, so doesn't need any constructor arguments, as demonstrated below:

```
// main.cpp
#include <mutex>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  std::mutex mutex[10];

  return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand the nature of the above compile error, and what an appropriate fix might be.

---

**Update**: @Jarod42 and @chris seem to have discovered this is a compiler bug. I'm updating the question to ask if anyone could explain the nature of this bug -- initiaizing member array-of-object elements seems like such a simple and foundational thing. What type of objects trigger this bug and why? I can't imagine this could be a universal/easily reproducible problem...?

---

**Update:** A not-great workaround seems to be making `B::A::A` an empty constructor and initializing `B::A::b_` with an rvalue. :(

```
// main.cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class B {
public:
  B();

private:

  class A {
    public:
      A() : b_( false ) {}

      bool b_;
      std::mutex mutex_;
      std::thread thread_;
  } a_[2];
};

B::B() { }

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  B b;

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -g ./main.cpp
$
```

Comment: It builds in current versions of GCC and Clang.

Comment: Seems indeed a gcc bug fixed in trunk as clang/msvc/gcc_trunk accepts it: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aYzEnf).

Comment: @chris - I tried at onlinegdb.com with their C++, C++14, and C++17 options, and all are able to reproduce the compile error (I'm assuming they use gcc).

Comment: The error is saying you can't copy a mutex. `std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)` is the copy constructor.

Comment: @StoneThrow, Presumably they use an old enough version then. I used godbolt to test trunk for each (as well as GCC 6.3), but it has enough choices that you can pinpoint which version fixed this.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - agreed: my assessment as well. chris and Jarod42 seem to have identified this as a compiler bug, and I'm inclined to agree, because after all, I'm not actually _copying_ mutexes here - I'm initializing array elements _in-place_.

Comment: To try to work around the bug, try to replace std::mutex with std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>. Get the mutex out of the class but conveniently accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent, likely cause of the bug is a subtle difference between copy-initialization and **copy-list-initialization**:

```
struct A {
  A(int);
  A(A&&)=delete;
} a=1,         // error: not movable
  b=A(1),      // error
  c={1},       // OK, no temporary constructed
  d[]={1},     // error
  e[]={A{1}},  // error
  f[]={{1}};   // OK (the compiler bug)
```

Here a bare `1` is **converted** to a temporary `A` which cannot be copied/moved, whereas `{1}` is used to **initialize** the ultimate `A` despite the term “copy”.  This distinction vanishes in C++17, where initialization from a prvalue (as for `b` or `a` after conversion) invokes **only** the prvalue’s constructor (“mandatory copy elision”).

The issue also couldn’t arise prior to C++11, since non-static array members could only be default- or value-initialized.  (`={}` was also considered normal copy-initialization then and didn’t apply to class objects at all.)  This is why your workaround worked, and the gradual **adoption** of the new initializers is probably why the compiler bug lasted as long as it did.

Note that, despite the error mentioning `std::mutex`’s deleted *copy* constructor, it is its non-*movability* that matters (as indicated by the `B::A::A(B::A&&)`), which is how it differs from `std::thread`.